# How to count records and display those counted records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im trying to have SQL count my records. However, I also need to be able to associate the actual records to that count. This handles the count just fine.

```
SELECT COUNT([ASSIGNED TO AS UserCount
FROM dbo.ECRSurvey
GROUP BY [ASSIGNED TO]
```

ASSIGNED TO actually contains a name. How can I have that name associated to the count so it outputs with the count? I hope that makes sense. If ASSIGNED TO contained 33 records of the name Jim, how can I get the query output to be 33 - Jim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(COUNT([ASSIGNED TO]) as varchar(10)) + ' - ' +  [ASSIGNED TO] as varchar(50))  AS UserCount
FROM dbo.ECRSurvey
GROUP BY [ASSIGNED TO]
```

Comment: Just trying to be precise. The SO asked for 33 - Jim

Comment: Yes sir! That did it exactly. I certainly appreciate the assistance!!! I thought it may be CAST but I could NOT get the syntax correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT [ASSIGNED TO], COUNT([ASSIGNED TO]) AS UserCount
FROM dbo.ECRSurvey
GROUP BY [ASSIGNED TO]
```